# MapDB: How to remove a HashMap?

Tags: java, mapdb

I have a MapDB with multiple HashMaps.

```
 DBMaker.Maker mapmk = DBMaker.fileDB (this.dbfile);
 DB mapdb = mapmk.make ();

 HTreeMap <String, String> map1 = mapdb.hashMap ("abc").createOrOpen ();
 map1.put("max", "123");

 HTreeMap <String, String> map2 = mapdb.hashMap ("def").createOrOpen ();
 map2.put("sam", "098");

 HTreeMap <String, String> map3 = mapdb.hashMap ("ghi").createOrOpen ();
```

How can I remove a whole map (e.g. map2 = "def") with all its key/value-pairs from the DB?

Comment: Which version are you using ?

Comment: Version is 3.0.8

Comment: The 3.0.8 code for the [DB class](https://github.com/jankotek/mapdb/blob/mapdb-3.0.8/src/main/java/org/mapdb/DB.kt#L30) contains the following comments:
//TODO consistency lock
//TODO rename nemed object
//TODO delete named object
//TOOD metrics logger

so apparently you cannot delete a named object/map in the v3 codebase yet. It did exist in version 2.